# string to json after getting value from redis ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I created a simple json object something like this:

```
a = {"b": 1, "c": 2}
```

Setting the json object as value in `redis` like this:

```
LocalCache.set('abc', a)
```

After getting the value from redis, I am getting a string value:

```
x = LocalCache.get('abc')
```

I want this string to be converted back to JSON object but I am unable to do it.

1. When I tried `x.as_json`, I am getting `"{:b=>1, :c=>2}"`
2. When I tried `x.to_json`, I am getting `"\"{:b=\\u003e1, :c=\\u003e2}\""`
3. When I tried `JSON.parse(x)`, I am getting this error:

   JSON::ParserError: 785: unexpected token at '{:b=>1, :c=>2}'

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Redis documentation: https://github.com/redis/redis-rb#storing-objects

Redis stores only strings as values. You have to serialize the value you are setting to as json and then parse it back as JSON after retrieving.

`a = {"b": 1, "c": 2}`

Here `a` is object of class `Hash`. Hence serialize while storing

```
x =  LocalCache.set("abc", a.to_json)
```

To retrieve: `x = JSON.parse LocalCache.get('abc')`

`p x` # `{"b"=>1, "c"=>2}`

Answer (score 3):

```
"{:b=>1, :c=>2}"
```

Is not valid json. It's a ruby hash. Cast it to json before cache-ing it and then parse it after you retrieve it.

```
LocalCache.set('abc', a.to_json)
x = LocalCache.get('abc')
JSON.parse(x)
```